# Print consequently horizontal text over many A4 papers

Tags: printing

I need a big text and to print it at home, I want to use just normal A4 papers, which will be then connected.
To get proper letter spacing, I need the printer to *tile* the text over the papers and split the letters if necessary.

[image: yellow written using Amelia font]

How would I do this?